# ceiling of an expression

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions

If we need to find the ceiling of  this expression

```
         (A-11)/100
```

then is it correct to simply write the above expression as

```
         (A-11+100)/100 .HERE we don't do any ceiling after evaluating this expression.
```

.Does both mean the same ?

Comment: Why would they be the same?

Answer (score 2):

They're are not the same:
$$
\left \lceil \frac{a-11+100}{100}\right\rceil=\left \lceil \frac{a-11}{100}+1\right\rceil=\left \lceil \frac{a-11}{100}\right\rceil+1
$$